# Remote Debugging from VS2013 getting Unable to Connect to Remote Debugging Monitor

Tags: remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug from Visual Studio 2013 to a remote server running Windows Server 2012.
I have run Msvsmon from my remote server and the Server Name in Options is FEP\build@DSS1Build1. I have set Windows Authentication and also given EVERYONE permission to Debug.
On Visual Studio on my own machine I do Attach to process and in the Qualifier field put the same Server name ie. FEP\build@DSS1Build1.
However when I press Refresh I get the message:

> "Unable to connect to Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging monitor... does not appear to be running on remote computer"

Is there something I need to unblock in the Firewall?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things need to be done.

1. On the remote server, you need to start Visual Studio Remote Debugging monitor and make sure you run it as a admin user (as otherwise you can't connect).
2. Make sure it is the right version (depends on if your server is 64bit or 32 bit).
3. Also you need to make sure that the remote debugging service is running. You can run the configuration wizard to see the status.
4. Then you need to put the full qualifier in as you mentioned.